# Perspective projection with multiple 3D objects on different depths in Python

Tags: python, 3d, rendering, projection, perspective

For my personal project I need to:

1. Produce a perspective projection from a 3D objet to a 2D plane (on a point defined in the space, which will be the camera).
2. Get the exact area/points coordinates of the perspective projectio
3. Produce the perspective projection of multiple 3D objects where some objects may be behind others.
4. Render the scene (only one image, there won't be any animation, so no need for a realtime rendering).

For points 1,2 and 4 I think I've found a way to do that using PyGame as described here:
http://codentronix.com/2011/04/21/rotating-3d-wireframe-cube-with-python/

But for point 3 I'm kind of stuck, because even if I can get the perspective projections for each of my objects, how can I know what object is really visible and which (full object or part of it) is not?

I really need to exactly know what parts of objects are visible and what parts are not, thus my ultimate goal would be to have a matrix of my screen image with the areas of every object's projection clearly defined.

For example, if the matrix contains all pixels of my screen image, and we have 10 objects, we would get 0 where there is no object, 1 where we can see object n1, 2 where object n2 is visible, etc..

I must add that I'm an accomplished developer in Python and many other languages, but I never did any game-related nor rendering development before.

Can someone help me get on the right tracks?

PS: side-question: if you could also point me to a better optimized implementation of perspective projection and rendering than PyGame, I'd be very interested!

Comment: I'm thinking maybe I should use an algorithm for collisions in 2D space? but the problem here is that I need the Z coordinate, which seems to also be returned along with the 2D projected point, but would this really be a viable solution (I'm really new to this kind of game stuff).

Comment: Have you tried OpenGL? There's a Python wrapper for it (PyOpenGL), which I have used to great success in a number of projects.

Comment: If you have the a perspective projection of each object, a simple way to do hidden-surface elimination is to draw them back to front. If they are composed of 3d polygons, you'd have to collect, sort, and draw all of those that way. Another relatively simple approach is to use a Z-buffer, which is basically keeping track of the z-value of surface shown at each pixel location in the image array. Of course, all this can be done for you, possibly in hardware, if you're allowed to use something like OpenGL or Direct3D (and have a wrapper for them).

Comment: Thank's for the ideas. Indeed I think I'll do the hidden-surface elimination by drawing from back to front.
I can use anything I want, but I've never used OpenGL before and since it's a low-level API I think it will be rather hard for me to manipulate.
What do you mean when you say that I can do this in hardware? Does OpenGL already has an existing function for hidden-surface elimination?

Comment: Finally I've gone with Panda3D as it is faster to prototype now, I can later switch to direct OpenGL interaction if needed for performances. Other alternatives are Soya3D, PySoy or cgkit, all work with Python, but Panda3D is definately the most advanced engine among those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use OpenGL for such tasks. Learning basic OpenGL (and this looks very basic) is not that much of an effort. Take a look [here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_01__05/22004/) (well known tutorial) and [here](http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/316) (basic example using Python, Qt and OpenGL). I think with some effort this might take you a day to get started.

Comment: Thank's for the links, didn't know them and they are welcomed.

However, this doesn't answer the real question so I just upvoted you.

Comment: still glad I could help you with the links -- it's worth the read.